# AWS com Route 53 - Domínio com WWW não funciona e HTTPS também não

Tags: servidor, dns, amazon-aws

É minha primeira experiência com AWS e tem sido bem complicada. 
Não tenho domínio de montagem de máquinas, nem roteamento de DNS e o que consegui até o momento foi criar uma instância do Beanstalk, fiz a configuração do banco de dados MYSQL e upload do site.

Na fase de testes, a solução funciona sem nenhuma falha.

Foi feita a configuração do Route 53, em seguida, registro das informações de NS's no Registro.br para propagação do domínio.

[image: Route53]
*Painel do Route53 - Foi feita a configuração em ambas URl's com e sem www.*

**Resultado: Sem utilização do www., funciona. Com utilização do www. não há retorno. E, em nenhum dos caso, o certificado SSL gerado pela Certificate Manager funcionou.**

[image: Certificate Manager]
*Painel do Certificate Manager, também foi criado para as duas URL's certificados SSL próprios.*

Utilizando o DNSChecker, detectei que a URL utilizando www e direcionada ao servidor antigo (hostgator) do site, não havendo a propagação correta para o novo servidor de hospedagem.

https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.mosteirodesaobento.com.br

Como posso proceder? O plano do meu cliente é o BASIC e não tenho como acionar o suporte.

Answer (score 0):

Após fazer backup da sua configuração atual, experimente:

1. Remover todas as entradas referentes ao site com www.
2. Criar um registro do tipo A com o endereço www apontando como ALIAS para o seu endereço sem www.

Comment: Fiz este procedimento. No DNS Checker, está apontando para o IP correto aparentemente. Mas ao tentar acessar via browser, dá timeout. Será que é apenas a propagação do DNS?

Comment: A propagação do DNS impactaria apenas na resolução do IP. Aparentemente o problema agora é com o ElasticBeanstalker. Ele tem alguma configuração relacionada ao certificado e CNAMEs?

Answer (score -1):

Tá meio estranho essas configurações. O mesmo conjunto de servidores DNS resolvem especificamente dois domínios? O www é só um subdomínio. Eu criaria os Servidores DNS para resolver o domínio raiz, que no teu caso é mosteirodesaobento.com.br e faria um redirecionamento 301 da versão com www para a versão raiz. Aqui tem um conjunto de artigos que explica sobre isso.
https://devcontent.com.br/criar-configurar-servidores-dns.html
Dê uma olhada, quem sabe te ajuda.

Abraços,

Airton